# How can I use jQuery to get asynchronous form feedback?

Tags: jquery, forms, asynchronous

I'm sure this might be a redundant question, but I don't know quite how to ask Google or SO in a way that makes sense.

If I've a form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <p><input type="text" name="number" id="num" /></p>
</form>
```

and I want to get feedback inside a span:

```
<span id="warning">Too high!</span>
```

if the entered number is too low or too high, how can I do this without having to use a submit button? Can this be done on the client side and without AJAX?

Comment: `$('#num').on('change',function(){...});` ???

Comment: Pretty sure this is it. Thanks! You should make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#num').change(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $warn = $('#warning');
  if ($this.val() > 100) {
    $warn.text('Too high!');
  }
  else {
    $warn.text('');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `onkeypress` event for reactivity:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pTvBV/)

```
$('#num').on('keypress',function () {
  var $warning = $('#warning');
  if (this.value > 100) {
    $warning.text('Too high!');
  }
  else {
    $warning.text('');
  }
});
```

Comment: Note: you used both $warning and $warn for the name.

Comment: @RoyJ So you catch me ;)  +1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If this is your HTML:

```
<form id="form1" action="process.php" method="post">
<p><input type="text" name="number" id="num" /></p>
<input type="button" onclick="checkNumber()" />
</form>
```

Then this JavaScript would do it:

```
function checkNumber() {
    var number = document.getElementById('num');
    if (number > 40) {
        document.getElementById('form1').innerHTML += '<span id="warning">Too high!</span>';
    }
}
```